# Purpose of Sales->Sales->Invoice and Packing Slip Design->Logo for HTML Print View in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, frontend, print, logo

What is the purpose of **Sales -> Sales -> Invoice and Packing Slip Design -> Logo for HTML Print View in Magento 2**

[image]

if the purpose is to change my account order print logo then **why it's not updating on frontend my account order print**.

I'm using Magento 2.1.2.

Comment: Have you run deploy command and remove var folder from root?

Comment: no. Let me try. For `Logo for PDF Print-outs` when I change it will work properly then why we need to deploy for HTML logo?.

Comment: @Rakesh still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Although this upload field exists in Magento's admin panel, I searched through the codebase and it's not currently used anywhere in the code. At this time Magento 2 does not show a logo on non-pdf printed orders, invoices or credit memos.

Comment: Have you checked customer my account order section? there is print order option is available.